# how to make openCV use GPU on google colab

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to make OpenCV use GPU on google Colab but I can' find any tutorial what I fond is this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/?fbclid=IwAR1D3_H_Jvw_v1pHIdF_R7nkGZL0jWiHqNyuSC3UcVsP2yjV-s2UHrPq7V8#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20%E2%80%9Cpip%2Dinstallable,proper%20NVIDIA%20GPU%20configurations%20set)

but I get stuck at step3 cuz this tutorial is not for colab

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d

Comment: I installed  OpenCV like the tutorial but it didn't use the GPU

Comment: @Axiumin_ that tutorial, great as it is, is for using the GPU with colab, not what the question requires

Comment: @all_alone I haven't tried it but it seems that in that tutorial, the standard version of opencv is installed, therefore CUDA is not installed. The tutorial does not provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

the default cv2 version installed on colab is 4.1.0 (very old !) and indeed, it has no CUDA support builtin. however, this is a google machine, it has all the tools, nooks & crannies to build your own ! latest cv2 ! with cuda ! (might take a good two hrs, though)

```
## 1st: switch to a gpu enabled runtime (from menu)

!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
!mkdir /content/build
%cd /content/build

!cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/content/opencv_contrib/modules  \
       -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
       -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
       -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
       -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
       -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF \
       -DWITH_CUDA=ON \
       -DWITH_CUBLAS=ON \
       -DWITH_CUDNN=ON \
       -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
       /content/opencv

!make -j8

## the new cv2.so is now in /content/build/lib/python3/
## you are not allowed a normal install on colab, (not root)
## but you can copy it into your work folder and restart the runtime, so it forgets about the old version !

import cv2
cv2.__version__

!ls -l

## save for later use:
!cp  /content/build/lib/python3/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so   "/content/drive/My Drive/cv2_cuda"

## next time, load it into your work folder:
## dont forget to restart the runtime, so it forgets about the old version !
!cp "/content/drive/My Drive/cv2_cuda/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" .
```